# HTTP GET to access LDAP

Tags: java, http, get, ldap

I am trying to write a code to access LDAP to get users and I need the result in a json array. I want to use HTTP get method but my experience in too low on this.Any ideas? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

When working with LDAP solutions, you're using the LDAP-protocol, and not HTTP.

You will need to get the directory entries with an LDAP-request (search by uid, samaccountname or similar) - and then from there convert the result to some kind of internal object that you can return through a service - e.g REST-based. This can return a JSON-object.

All of this can be done using e.g:

- Unboundid for ldap
- Spring to handle requests and returning objects as json

Hope this helps getting you a bit closer on what you'll need to do.

Comment: All this can be done *without* UnboundId *or* Spring. JNDI and a Servlet is quite sufficient.

Comment: Well what I need is a HTTP interface and I think that is possible to be done. I have no experience in writing such a code so any suggestions would be welcome

Comment: @EJP, yes thats right - but as it exists a lot of tutorials on those libraries/functionalities I thought that it would be easier for a person new to configuring all these things with the use of quite simple elements - such as Spring and UnboundId..

Comment: @Alma LDAP is a protocol (P) to access (A) a directory (D). So your question bils down to "I want to use this protocol but want to use another protocol" which does not make too much sense. The directory you want to access might other a HTTP-interface besides an LDAP-interface, but you would not be using LDAP then...

Answer (score 0):

Accessing LDAP over HTTP is "easily" possible, if your LDAP server supports a REST API or DSML.  Not every LDAP server does, though.